# Как массово сменить названия классов html+css? Сайт на WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Как массово сменить названия классов html+css? Сайт на WP. Возможно есть какой-то плагин или php-библиотека? Нужно массовое решение, вручную менять все имена классов в темах на кучи сайтов не вариант. Не обязательно готовое решение для WP, нужна любая зацепка. Единственное что я нашел, это дополнение для gulp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css-names
Может кто-то встречал что-то подобное на php?

Comment: Какие именно? Где? зачем? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6689 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Все названия классов которые есть в шаблоне. В шаблоне. Нужно.

Comment: Не в шаблоне, а теме. И тогда исправь вопрос.

Comment: И вопрос не имеет никого отношения к php. Не ставь эту метку. (рискуешь что неграмотные в ВП, но с высокой репой закроют твой пост)

Comment: Видимо вы не поняли суть вопроса, я его немного дополнил, надеюсь сейчас будет более понятно.

Answer (score 0):

В своей  дочерней теме можно прописывать любой hml и css

Матчасть: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: Совсем не то что нужно

Comment: Когда я писал ответ ни про какие кучи сайтов речи не было.